# MQTT protocol NGINX

Tags: ios, nginx, mqtt

I am currently planning to use `MQTT` protocol for a pub/sub app in `IOS`. My backend server is `NGINX` and I want to connect it using `websockets`. I haven't used `MQTT` before so my question is can I configure my `NGINX` server to be the message broker for the `MQTT` protocol  or do I have to use `NGINX` as a `proxy server` for a message broker such as `mosquitto` library running on a different instance.

Comment: You'd need a MQTT server/broker such as mosquitto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nginx is not a MQTT broker, at best nginx can proxy for a broker but it can not act as one.

Nginx can proxy both native MQTT and MQTT over websockets when configured correctly.

The instance of the broker doesn't have to run on a separate machine, but you can use Nginx as a load balancer across a cluster of brokers if needed.